# What's an umbrella term for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division?

Tags: word-request

What's an umbrella term for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division? What do you individually call each of these: 1+2, 5-2, 3*4, 10/5? Those cannot be "problems". Are those operations? Note the absence of equal signs

Comment: If you google your question, you will find several sites that give you the answer.

Comment: In colloquial parlance, arithmetic problems. In formal texts, arithmetical operations.

Comment: Numeracy might be a good choice.

Comment: @Lambie that is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

The four basic arithmetic **operations** are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

The common symbols used are

addition
`+` e.g. `3 + 5`

subtraction
`-` e.g. `5 - 2`

multiplication `×` e.g. `5 × 2`
this is not the letter 'x' in the alphabet, although many people use that when typing informally. Also this symbol `⋅` may be used in formal mathematical material e.g. `5 ⋅ 2`.
The asterisk `*` e.g. `5 * 2` is used mainly in computer code for convenience (as `×` is not easily typed), and may be found in informal material.

division
`/` e.g. `6 / 2`
or
`÷` e.g. `6 ÷ 2`

[Arithmetic operations (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Arithmetic_operations)

Comment: Yes, in everyday parlance, we say problems.

Comment: They are not problems to everyone.

Comment: Can it be called both operation and problem, without equal signs?

Comment: "As we know, basic arithmetic questions involve simple **addition/subtraction/multiplication/division problems**. Let’s solve problems in arithmetic here in this article". https://byjus.com/maths/arithmetic-questions/ See, Michael? I knew he would come at you. So, I was just trying to head it off at the pass and not have a pissing contest (idiom). Also, I upvoted your answer, fyi.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - let us say you think of a number, suppose it is 5. Then you think of another number, suppose it is 2. Now you add them together. The answer is 7. _What you did in your head_ is an arithmetic **operation**, called **addition**. You **added** 5 and 2. Now suppose your teacher hands you a piece of paper and on it is `5 + 2 = ` and you have to write the answer. That is a **problem**. A problem is something you have to solve. To solve this one, you have to perform an addition operation.

Comment: @Lambie - do you think I made it clearer?

Comment: It was already clear.  I just added what people say colloquially.

Comment: So 5+2 cannot be called an operation? "Operation" can only refer to an action, e.g. addition, can't it? If so, Lambie seems to disagree

Comment: They're "problems" in a schoolroom, certainly. "Sums" is also common but sometimes synonymous with addition. "Operation" would normally be used for the abstract process of addition/subtraction/etc ("Multiplication is an operation") rather than a specific expression like "2+4" ("2+4 is a sum"). "Equation" might upset mathematicians, but pfft. Context is everything.

Answer (score 1):

They are the (four) basic arithmetic operators. As the [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Arithmetic_operations) explains there are other arithmetic operators but these four are the basic ones.

Comment: I have no idea why Michael Harvey removed his perfectly good answer. Anyway, they are operations, not operators. The signs are operators.

Answer (score 0):

An umbrella term is ***four-function arithmetic***.

Manufacturers and marketers of electronic calculators, speak of a **basic *four-funtion* calculator**.

Comment: Roll out the barrel! (old song)

Comment: I need a countable noun for each of those lines

Comment: "There are three four-function calculators in our inventory." What's wrong with that? They are perfectly countable.

Comment: 2+3 is not a calculator

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev But a "Four-function calculator" IS a calculator. It is no different to a "five-geared car". There are a countable number of those in the showroom.